# Can't start vsftpd on Fedora

Tags: fedora, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd on my new Eee pc with Fedora 18:

```
sudo yum install vsftpd
```

How is it? :

```
systemctl is-active vsftpd.service
```

and got

```
failed
```

Then

```
systemctl status vsftpd.service
```

got

```
Failed to start Vsftpd demon
Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state
```

What is the best way to start repairing vsftpd?

Comment: Check `/var/log` for it's logs, `/etc` for it's configuration, maybe type `dmesg` to check if it isn't some bigger problem.

Comment: Please post the _full_ output of `systemctl status vsftpd.service`, it should include enough logs to find out what is going on.

Comment: Fedora doesn't automatically start services once you install the package -- you need to enable and start them yourself.  Did you do either of those?

Answer (score 0):

By default vsftpd will listen on ipv6. Need to change it to ipv4 mode with the below modification to the file `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`:

Existing entry:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
```

Change it to:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```

Then start the vsftpd service:

```
systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess your `vsftpd` was never started.
You may need to try to start it manually through `/etc/init.d/vsftpd start` and examine system logs for what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same error and I saw in the vsftpd status that the error was in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

so, I just write (or uncomment):

```
listen_ipv6=NO
```

And then I could start vsftpd service with any problems